# How to print a table from a 2D Array in Angular 5?

Tags: html, arrays, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to print a table from a 2 dimensional array of objects, holding a attribute 'text'. It only prints the table rows, iterating through the fields doesn't work.

My component.html looks like this:

```html
<section *ngIf="object">
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of array; let even = even; let odd = odd"
          [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }">
        <td class="field" *ngFor="let field of array[row]">
          {{field.text}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
```

The array: object[][] is filled correctly and i can log the 'text' attributes to the console. The Problem is: I don't know how to iterate through the 2nd dimension (`*ngFor="let field of array[row]"`)

Comment: Small side note, you don't need to add odd/even class to your elements, you can use plain CSS: `table > tr:nth-of-type(odd)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `array` is an array of arrays,

Your second `ngFor` should be `*ngFor="let field of row"`

You can't use `array[row]` since `row` contains the array of the second dimension and not the index.

```
<section *ngIf="object">
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of array; let even = even; let odd = odd"
          [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even }">
        <td class="field" *ngFor="let field of row">
          {{field.text}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </section>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-of-arrays-print)